# Is there a way to show text in plotly graph tooltip without being overlapped?

Tags: javascript, css, plotly.js

As shown in codepen below, text value for trace 1 is being trimmed as it is close to chart border.
Need to show these numbers above everything else. Have tried setting z-index. Didn't worked.

https://codepen.io/satishvarada/pen/yLVoqqo

```
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [16, 16, 16, 16],
  type: 'scatter',
  text:[16, 16, 16, 16],
  textposition:'top',
  mode:'lines+markers+text'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [16, 5, 11, 9],
  type: 'scatter',
  mode:'lines+markers+text'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

[image: Trimmed text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```css
.plot { clip-path: none; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a `plotly` user, but here is my try:

#### The problem:

Plotly has a default `height` of `450px` and it also uses some default values regarding its `layout` settings which can be found at the documentation [here](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/#layout-margin). Since you are trying to plot something with smaller height (`350px`), you can adjust a little bit the default `layout` values to make the text fit better. Below, I have just set smaller `margin` values, for example `40` instead of `80`,`80`,`80`,`100` which are the defaults and it seems to work.

#### Solution:

```
var layout = {
  autosize: true,
  height: 350,
  margin: {
      l: 40,
      r: 40,
      b: 40,
      t: 40,
      pad: 0
    },
};
var config = {responsive: true}
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, config);
```

(notice that I set the `height` at the layout object and I have removed it from the `style` property of your `div`)

#### Working example:

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [16, 16, 16, 16],
  type: 'scatter',
  text:[16, 16, 16, 16],
  textposition:'top',
  mode:'lines+markers+text'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [16, 5, 11, 9],
  type: 'scatter',
  mode:'lines+markers+text'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];
// var data = [trace1];
var layout = {
  autosize: true,
  height: 350,
  margin: {
      l: 40,
      r: 40,
      b: 40,
      t: 40,
      pad: 0
    },
};
var config = {responsive: true}


Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, config);
```

```html
<head>
    <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='myDiv'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</body>
```

Comment: myDiv size is not standard. It could be even smaller than 350px. Rather than adjusting margins, looking for a CSS fix that shows the numbers on top of everything.

Comment: I think it's more complicated to look at the `svg` generated by plotly and then try to override how it looks with `css`, but it's up to you if you want to follow this path :-) Also, I still believe that for low-height graphs one will inevitably end up modifying the layout object because there is a lot of white-space by default. Anyway, let's see what the others will answer...

Comment: Oh, and another possible solution might be to use `textposition:'bottom'` instead of `top`